# Google maps marker.AdvancedMarkerElement is Undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to migrate from the legacy Marker map element to the newer AdvancedMarkerElement following this documentation, but I'm finding marker.AdvancedMarkerElement is undefined:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/migration

I've updated the script tag loading the libraries based on information here to include the (advanced)marker library:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries

This is now:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxx&libraries=places,marker,drawing,geometry&loading=async&callback=onMapsLoaded"></script>`

The map initialization was updated to include an id, not that this seems to be relevant;\

```
let pos = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.031 };
_map = new google.maps.Map(
    $('#dMap')[0], { 
        zoom: 4, 
        center: pos, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, 
        mapId: 'DEMO_MAP_ID' 
    }
);
```

According to the documentation I should be changing **google.maps.Marker** to **google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement**.

```
let pos = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.031 };
let marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    position: pos,
    map: _map,
    title: 'Some title'
});
```

Attempting to create a new marker this way fails however, since google.maps.**marker** is undefined, as obviously is google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement.

Anyone have any idea why this is?

I've looked at the script returned, and it has mentions to AdvancedMarkerElement throughout it, so I'd assume that the library is in fact loaded.

Is there some reference that I'm missing?  Do I need to define or call some function so that google.maps.marker is defined?  And if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code that throws? Is it in the `onMapsLoaded`? You probably would be better off promissifying anyway

Comment: It throws when attempting to create the AdvancedMarkerElement because google.maps.marker is null.

Comment: I understand. What I'm asking is how you determine when the maps library has been loaded because that error will occur if you try to  use the library before that.

Comment: Ah you were right.  I'd mark your comment as the answer - The rest of the code was being called from the callback on the  tag; script &callback=onMapsLoaded.  

However there was old additional code initialized the page that was not removed when it should have been after the &loading=async parameter was added to the library loading script tag.

$(document).ready(function () { geofenceedit.prepareform(); });

Comment: That is NOT how you should be loading the API. The docs has all examples. And `loading=async` has never been an API parameter.

Comment: loading was added in API v3.55.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api#use-legacy-tag

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
const {AdvancedMarkerElement} = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
```

then

```
const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
            //const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map,
            position: { lat: 0, lng: -29 }
        });
```

Works for me.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map#maps_add_map-javascript

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).