# Google maps marker.AdvancedMarkerElement is Undefined Error

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-advanced-marker-element

I am trying to load [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/migration) into a C# ASP.Net server. I am getting an error message: Google maps marker.AdvancedMarkerElement is undefined

Reference Code:

1. Report.cshtml
   Note: Insert your API key

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}
<div id="map"></div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            const position = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.031 };

            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: position,
                mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID", // Map ID is required for advanced markers.
            });

            // The advanced marker, positioned at Uluru
            const marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
                map,
                position: position,
                title: 'Uluru',
            });
        };
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.initMap = initMap;
        });
        
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxx&callback=initMap&v=weekly&loading=async"
            defer>
    </script>
}
```

2. Controller

```
using FastTestMap.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FastTestMap.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Report()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to run the above example using the example provided on Google Advance Marker Element and I think the problem is with the way the library is getting loaded. I believe that the library is deferring its load, therefore the advance marker is undefined.

I tried the [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78104425/google-maps-marker-advancedmarkerelement-is-undefined) in comments to no end.

Comment: As commented by @Aluan Haddad in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78104425/google-maps-marker-advancedmarkerelement-is-undefined, make sure that the maps library is loaded before the code that tries to use it. You can check the loading order in the Network tab of your browser's developer tool.

Comment: I forgot to reply to the solution. There is no issue with the code. I had made a typo, hence I was facing an error. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add marker library

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries